# awk + how to capture email address between characters

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have a very long list of emails between the `<` and `>` characters:

```
smeimebv2t <jdyefc@nsuwtcvc>; jdedyvt <ejd2ydt2@dv2dg2vgv>; didi2jd2m     <i2dmi32@hd2vdg >; 3idm23i2m <2udhu2@cdrrc>
.
.
.
```

How can I use an awk or perl one liner in order to capture only the emails addresses between the `< >`?

example:

```
more results.out

jdyefc@nsuwtcvc
ejd2ydt2@dv2dg2vgv
i2dmi32@hd2vdg
2udhu2@cdrrc
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is using GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '<\K[^>]+(?=>)' file 
jdyefc@nsuwtcvc
ejd2ydt2@dv2dg2vgv
i2dmi32@hd2vdg 
2udhu2@cdrrc
```

The `-o` means "only print matching region of the line" and the `-P` activates Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. These let us use `\K` which means "don't consider anything matched up to this point as part of the match" and [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). So, the regex will match an `<`, then any stretch of non `>` characters followed by a `>`.

Note that this will also match `<foo>` which isn't an email. To restrict to emails only (strings with a `@`), you can use:

```
grep -Po '<\K[^>]+@[^>]+(?=>)' file
```

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -lne 'print for /<\K[^>]+/g'
```

Answer (score 4):

Using gawk:

```
awk -v RS="[<>]" '/@/'
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity, but it's worth mentioning that there better be no other at signs in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 while /<(.*?)>/g'
```

The parenthesis capture to `$1`, `.*?` makes the match non-greedy, i.e. stops as soon as it can.

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'<' '{ for(i = 2 ; i <= NF ; i++) { sub(/>.*/, "", $i); print $i; } } '
```

Split the line on `<`'s, ignore the first part, print others after removing anything starting with `>`. This will print the the rest of the line if there is no `>` after a `<`.